# Highchart date quarter view on axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How to adjust axis in bar chart so that first month of every quarter will be displayed as axis point for the given time interval.

for example :-
if start year is 2012 and end year is 2013 then axis should be displayed as

`jan 2012, apr 2012, jul 2012, Oct 2012 , jan 2013, apr 2013, jul 2013, Oct 2013`

[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/BrbWt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yAxis:  {      
 type: 'datetime',
 min: Date.UTC(2012,0,1),
 title: {text: ''},
 tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 *30 * 4,
 labels: {
 formatter: function() {
  var d= new Date(this.value);
  var month = d.getMonth();
  var monArr=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
  return monArr[month] + " - " + d.getFullYear();
  }
}
```

Comment: There are 4 quarters in a year with 3 months per quarter. Your tickInterval should be 24*3600*1000*30*3.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of arrays, you can set tickInterval and in formatter use Highcharts.dateFormat();

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.dateFormat